# Can my Nikon D750 fire a flash while I'm connected to it over wifi?

Tags: nikon, flash, wifi

I'm trying to take photos from my iPad using the wifi connection on my D750, but I can't get the setup to trigger my flash when I take photos that way. Is this a thing that can be done?

Comment: Can you add more info?  What tethering software are you using?  Is it the pop-up or a hotshoe flash?  What mode is the camera in (P,A,S,M). If you walk over and press the shutter does the flash fire?

Comment: Are you shooting in a situation where the flash must fire? In many combinations of exposure and flash modes, the flash will not fire if there is enough ambient light to light the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Probably using a Cam Ranger system. A quick visit to their [website](https://camranger.com/knowledge-base/nikon-d750/) will tell you that it is compatible with both their older system and the new Cam Ranger-Mini